# Business Layer not recognizing Function Imports or Complex Typed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have something that I'm working on and am running to an  issues I cant seem to resolve (Like that's a shocker right). One of my classes isn't recognizing Complex Types, or Function Imports. It keeps asking for **GetCategories** which is clearly in the Function Imports. Here's the screen shots to verify it's there:

[image: Complex Types]

[image: Function Imports]

[image: StoredProcedure]

[image]

And this is the only piece of code that uses any of those:

```
public class StoreIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GetCategories> storeCategories { get; set; }
}
```

This is the error returned on IEnumerable

> Error 1 The type or namespace name
>   'GetCategories' could not be found 
>   (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)
>   F:\Projects\GodsCreationTaxidermySVN\GodsCreationTaxidermy\ViewModels\StoreIndexViewModel.cs  11  28  GodsCreationTaxidermy

Can anyone tell me why this class (and only this class) has this problem?

**EDIT:** I also noticed that the Complex Types show up in my TT's but not the Function Imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your complex type is called `GetCagetories_Result` then your type will be also `GetCategories_Result` so you must use:

```
public class StoreIndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<GetCategories_Result> storeCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My question(sound advice, I'll try it hen I get VS open again) is why it doesn't use the FuntionImports instead of the Complex types.

Comment: Function import is not a type. `IEnumerable<T>` expects type. Function import is just some call structure exposed for `ObjectContext` - usually wrapped by the method with the same name calling `context.ExecuteFunction`

Comment: It's not even recognizing GetCagetories_Result. Now I get "The type or  namespace 'etCategories_Resuls' could not be found

Comment: Did you reference assembly with your model? Did you define correct using?

Comment: Yes sir I added 'using GodsCreationTaxidermy.Data;' and altered the method to be public IEnumerable<GetCagetories_Result> storeCategories { get; set; }noe I get an error about GetCategories_Result

Comment: Your statement about 'Did you reerence assemvbly with your model? you reference with your model, did you define correctly; almost had me confused'